# How to prefund a hardhat local node address

Tags: ethereum, web3js, hardhat

On spinning up a hardhat node locally, I get 10 addresses pre funded with 10k ETH. But none of these show up on metamask when I connect it to localhost:8545. As a result I'm not able to interact with a dapp deployed locally

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

MetaMask has no way of knowing which of your local accounts you want to import, or which are funded (prior to the import).

So you need to import the accounts to MetaMask manually using the private keys provided by Hardhat.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I realized there's another way to fund them using the hardhat faucet
___
npx hardhat --network localhost faucet <address to be funded>

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the back-end development project provides funded accounts which you can enter into Metamask,  It's not like the Goerli or (now defunct) Rinkeby test networks where you can visit a site and have some ETH added to your test account because those test networks are hosted.  You need to spin up a local project and have it provide funded accounts.

Such an example is Lesson 9: Hardhat Smart Contract Lottery in (Learn Blockchain, Solidity, and Full Stack Web3 Development with JavaScript by Free Code Camp)

here is the code ...

https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc

If you run that project it generates a number of addresses which you can connect to in Metamask.

[image]